# Possible to search for transactions by 'escrow_status' with Braintree API?

Tags: braintree

I'd like to [search for transactions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search/python) associated with my merchant_id, which have a certain escrow status. Something along these lines:

```
collection = braintree.Transaction.search(
    braintree.TransactionSearch.escrow_status == 'hold_pending'
)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

Searching for transactions based on `escrow_status` is not supported by our api at this time. A workaround is to collect all transactions for a particular time period and manually filter these based on escrow status.

Comment: Thank you - I spoke to your tech support crew, and we sorted it out. Hopefully, searching by escrow is a feature that can be implemented soon, as searching for a superset of your desired results, and filtering it, places an unnecessary load on both Braintree's servers, and on clients' systems.

Comment: Hi @pblesi, do you know if searching for transactions based on `escrow_status` is now supported?

Comment: Hi @PatNeedham, another Braintree employee here and would also encourage you to contact our [awesome support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you want further assistance with your specific use case.  Unfortunately we do still do not support searching on `escrow_status`, so the workaround suggested by @pblesi is your best bet.